# Substring before throwing error

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I've the below XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<body>
 <p>Industrial drawing: Any creative composition</p>
   <p>Industrial drawing: Any creative<fn>
          <fnn>4</fnn>
          <fnt>
            <p>ftn1"</p>
          </fnt>
        </fn> composition
      </p>
</body>
```

and the below XSL.

```
<xsl:template match="p">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="contains(substring-before(./text(),' '),'Article')">
            <xsl:text>sect3</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="./text()"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="contains(substring-before(./b/text(),' '),'Section')">
            <xsl:text> Sect 2</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="./text()"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="contains(substring-before(./b/text(),' '),'Chapter')">
            <xsl:text> Sect 1</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="./text()"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>

</xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

Here my XSL is working fine for `<p>Industrial drawing: Any creative composition</p>` but for the below Case

```
 <p>Industrial drawing: Any creative<fn>
      <fnn>4</fnn>
         <fnt>
            <p>ftn1"</p>
         </fnt>
      </fn> composition
 </p>
```

it is throwing me the below error.

```
XSLT 2.0 Debugging Error: Error: file:///C:/Users/u0138039/Desktop/Proview/ASAK/DIFC/XSLT/tabel.xslt:38: Wrong occurrence to match required sequence type -   Details: -     XPTY0004: The supplied sequence ('2' item(s)) has the wrong occurrence to match the sequence type xs:string ('zero or one')
```

please let me know how can i fix this and grab the text required.

Thanks

Comment: Shouldn't `substring-before(./text(),'')` be `substring-before(./text(),' ')` i.e. substring before a **space**?

Comment: Hi @michael.hor257k, I've a small doubt if i have something like <p><b><c>Chapter 12</c></b></p>, is there a way that i can get the text without using `substring-before(./b/c/text(), ' ')` i mean a direct type like using `*` . Thanks

Comment: Doesn't the answer by Ian Roberts cover that possibility?

Comment: @michael.hor257k, This type is not working if the content is inside child nodes as stated above

Comment: Solved it @michael.hor257k, Thanks for the help, I used `contains(substring-before(string-join(descendant-or-self::*/text()[fn:not(self::fnn)], ''),' '),'Article')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `p` element in your example has several text nodes, so the expression `./text()` creates a sequence. You cannot apply a string function to a sequence; you must convert it to a string first. Instead of:

```
test="contains(substring-before(./text(),' '),'Article')"
```

try:

```
test="contains(substring-before(string-join(text(), ''), ' '), 'Article')"
```

Answer (score 2):

The second `p` element in your example XML has *two* child text nodes, one containing "Industrial drawing: Any creative" and the other containing a space, "composition", a newline and another six spaces.  In XSLT 1.0 it is legal to apply a function that expects a string to an argument that is a set of more than one node, the behaviour is to take the value of the first node and ignore all the others.  But in 2.0 it is a type mismatch error to pass two nodes to a function that expected a single value for its parameter.

But in this case I doubt that you really need to use `text()` at all - if all you care about is seeing whether the string "Article" occurs anywhere within the first word under the `p` (including when this is nested inside another element) then you can simply use `.`:

```
<xsl:when test="contains(substring-before(.,' '),'Article')">
```

(or better still, use predicates to separate the different conditions into their own templates, with one template matching "Article" paragraphs, another matching "Section" paragraphs, etc.)